# Query AWS DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm completely new to DynamoDB, and I can't find out how query works.

So, in my case, I have a table(collection/etc) `Users` with this fields and AWS types in brackets:

`id [type String], name [type String], email[type String], ref_code[type Map], register_date[type String]`

And my table Indexes are

```
KeySchema: [
  { AttributeName: 'id', KeyType: 'HASH' },
  { AttributeName: 'register_date', KeyType: 'RANGE' },
],
AttributeDefinitions: [
  { AttributeName: 'id', AttributeType: 'S' },
  { AttributeName: 'register_date', AttributeType: 'S' },
],
```

I've read documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html?shortFooter=true), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Query.html) and a lot of other info too, but still can't understand how can I query user by his/her name.
So, in MySQL world if I have primary index on field Id, I still can query user data by his/her name, like this `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '<name>';`
But, this behaviour isn't work with DynamoDB.
I've tried to query like this:

```
var params = {
TableName: 'Users',
IndexName: 'name',
KeyConditionExpression: '#u_name = :name',
ProjectionExpression: '#u_name, lives, fb_account',
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
  '#u_name': 'name',
},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ':name': 'Mykhaylo',
},
};
```

And a lot of other options, but nothing worked out.

So, my question is **How to make query in AWS DynamoDB?**

**EDIT**

If I need to set more than 5 global second indexes, how should I perform my query? 
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly query on the field which is not hash key. You have to either use `scan` with `filter` on `name` like

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'Users',
    FilterExpression: '#u_name = :value',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#u_name': 'name'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':value': 'Mykhaylo'
    },
};
docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
   ////////
});
```

**or** you need to create a [`gsi`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) with `name` as `hash key`. Then you can use [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) to get the result according to `name`

Comment: Thank you. I've read here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-secondary-indexes that I can have max 5 secondary indexes for table. But what if all my columns possibly could become required?
For example, table with fields: id, name, email, city, country, gender, subscription.
And I'd like to use all of them and make requests to find user by any of this fields

Comment: @Grynets You cannot create more than 5 gsi. You can always use `scan` and `filter` (as I described in the answer) to get data using any field. The only problem with `scan` is that it will be very slow for large dataset. So if you have a large dataset and facing performance problem with `scan`, then you might have to create a separate table to create `gsi` on more fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can run sql queries against dynamodb by doing the following:

- open ubuntu bash
- `pip install dql`
- `dql -r eu-west-2`
- `scan * from table_name;`